# mysql_fetch_array() issue

Tags: php, mysql

The below is throwing the following error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /home/zyquo/public_html/ghosthuntersportal.com/product_process.php
>   on line 33

```
Line 33 is: while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($result11)){

elseif($_GET['do']=="add"){
$sql10="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (product_name, product_price, product_category, product_link, product_image, product_tag, product_features, product_pros, product_cons, product_description, product_notes) VALUES ('$product_name', '$product_price', '$product_category', '$product_link', '$product_image', '$product_tag', '$product_features', '$product_pros', '$product_cons', '$product_description', '$product_notes')";
mysql_query($sql10);
$sql11="SELECT product_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE product_name=".$product_name."";
$result11=mysql_query($sql11);
while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($result11)){
$product_id2=$row11['product_id'];
$sql12="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (keyword,product_id) VALUES ('$keyword','$product_id2')";
mysql_query($sql12);
}
}
```

query sql10 runs and inserts the data, query sql11 does not run.

Comment: If you ever have this kind of error, look at the output of `mysql_error()` after the offending query.

Comment: Why do you need so many vars for sql text result? Take one and reuse it. Or use array with cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to try with single quote for ".$product_name."

```
$sql11 = "SELECT product_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE product_name='" . $product_name . "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `mysql_fetch_array()`, it is with the preceding `mysql_query()`, and thus is a problem with your query string `$sql11`.

Your code looks like this:

```
$sql11="SELECT product_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE product_name=".$product_name."";
```

It would help to know what `$tbl_name` and `$product_name` are, particularly `$product_name`. You haven't told us whether you've escaped `$product_name` or not, or added quotes to it, but I'll have to assume you haven't.

In a SQL query, all strings must be in quotes. (You have quotes in the code, but those are PHP quotes, and will not end up in the query).

Therefore, you should change your query to add quotes, as follows:

```
$sql11="SELECT product_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE product_name='".$product_name."'";
```

However, this isn't the end of the issue, as you will still have problems if `$product_name` itself contains a quote character. Because of this, you should also ensure that variables in a SQL query are properly escaped, using the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

Therefore (assuming you haven't already escaped the `$product_name` variable), you code should now look like this:

```
$sql11="SELECT product_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE product_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($product_name)."'";
```

Finally, you should do some basic error checking when you do a SQL query. You can do this by checking whether `$result` is false, and if so, by using the `mysql_error()` function to determine the nature of the error. Errors can occur because of bad query string (as is likely in this case), but also because of connection issues with the database itself or a number of reasons that may not be bugs in your code. Therefore, after every `mysql_query()`, you should always check that an error hasn't occurred before proceeding. (it is up to you to decide what to do if there is an error!). Being able to cope with unexpected errors is critical, and often makes the difference between a good program and a bad one.

I hope that helps.